# Make Javascript Function Based on a Variable, Where Changing Variable Does Not Change Function

Tags: javascript, function

I want to create a Javascript function based on the state of a variable at that time, and when the variable changes, the function should not change. Like I want something where like:

```
let x = "A";
function f() {
  ????
}
x = "B";
f(); // Prints A, not B.
```

Neither of these below worked:

```
function f() {
  console.log(x);
}
```

```
function f() {
  let y = x + "";
  console.log(y);
}
```

These worked but I am worried that they access memory after it has been freed:

```
function g(y) {
  return () => {
    console.log(y);
  };
}
let f = g(x);
```

```
function g() {
  let y = x + "";
  return () => {
    console.log(y);
  };
}
let f = g();
```

How do I do this right?

Comment: JavaScript uses automatic garbage collection. Nothing is freed if it can still be accessed.

Comment: In what context would that kind of function possibly be useful? The whole point of a variable is that it can change. If you want the value of the variable `x` as it was at a specific time, and (important!) that value is a *primitive*, you can just declare a new variable equal to `x` and then use the new variable in your function. If the value of `x` was primitive, the new variable won't change when `x` changes. But, since you already have the value in the new variable, why have the function return it at all? Example: `var x = "A"; var z = x; x = "B";` and `z` will still be `"A"`.

Comment: would you be using a global variable if you want the state to not change? Why not use classes and init them correctly?

Answer (score 2):

You can use an IIFE:

```js
let x = "A";
const f = (() => {
  let y = x;
  return () => y;
})();
x = "B";
console.log(f());
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to achieve this programatically without having any memory leaks / global declarations (technically, depending where you declare `let x`), is to create a closure over a callback with the function in a following fashion:

```js
let x = "A";
let f = (function(x) {
  return function() {
    console.log(x);
  };
})(x);

x = "B";
f(); // Prints A
```

The way this works, that it stores a reference as an argument and the callback accesses that reference for the inner (lambda) function instead of pointing reference to the `let x` declaration in memory.

Note, the IIFE (self-invoked) function, at the end of the expression passing the argument

```js
})(x); // self-invoked
```

---

To anyone curious why this happens in the first place, it's because JavaScript compiler employs hoisting, which moves declarations up so they are not in the order it may appear to a human eye in the code snipping and the function in the OP's question points to a memory reference which already is changed by the statement `x = 'B'`

Comment: I might also add to my answer, I fail to see usefulness of this in a real-world application. It may be likely you're trying to circumvent some behaviour without handling it properly, would be smart to post why you're trying to achieve this as well